Apex AutoConvert
I am not a pro with Apex and was able to find code that would autoconvert leads which is working well.  Now I've been asked to have the autoconverted Accounts have a specific owner assigned.  I attempted to do this with a flow to run as soon as the Account is created.  It is not working.  So now I'm wondering if I can assign the Account Owner at the moment of Autoconvert.  Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.  Here is the Apex code I'm currently using.
public class AutoConvertLeads {
   @InvocableMethod   
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)  
    {
        LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT ID, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted = true Limit 1];
        List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List <Database.LeadConvert>();
        for(id currentlead: LeadIds){
            DATABASE.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new DATABASE.LeadConvert(); 
            Leadconvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                               
            Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.MasterLabel);             
            MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert); 
        }
        if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty())
        {
           List<DATABASE.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);    
        }
    }   
}


Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.

When you say I attempted to do this with a flow to run as soon as the Account is created. It is not working. What is not working, are you getting exception, if yes what kind of exception, how are you updating owner to account, can you share some more info here?

This can be done with a flow -- run Flow on Lead when it becomes converted; the Lead record will have field ConvertedAccountId that you use to Get / Update the Account

The flow debug is showing that it should be working.  However, on actual tests in the Sandbox, the Owner does not change.

cropredy - are you saying I should run the flow on the Lead object assigning the owner before conversion?

no -- run the Lead Flow when IsConverted = true, then flow logic can set Account.OwnerId to whatever you want

can't you update the lead owner with the account owner, so the standard mapping for lead convert works?
